# Displaying a locator that moves smoothly and updates some dynamic variables

Tags: graphics, dynamic

I want to select a point on a graph and display a function of the coordinates value. Asking here a related question I learned to use Setting. Consider the example, where I display the coordinate `x` and its double `2*x`:

```
Manipulate[
 xp = Dynamic[First[pt]];
 z = Setting[2*xp];
 Column[{
   Style[StringForm["x=`1`, z=`2`", xp, z], Blue, 16],
   LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],
    ListPlot[{{0, 0}},
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[Dynamic[pt]]}
     ]]}, Center],
 {{pt, {0, 0}}, None}
 ]
```

By clicking on the graph, the value of `x` and `z = 2*x` is correctly displayed above the graph. However, one cannot move the `Locator` smoothly, each point must be clicked!

The problem is caused by `Setting`. By removing it, the point can be moved around smoothly, `x` is displayed dynamically but then the `z` is not calculated but displayed as `2 x`. 
Is it possible to display the value of `z` without loosing the fluency in the point selection? Is there a different way to get the value of `z` without using `Setting`?

Comment: I think using `Setting` here may not be proper. According to [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Setting.html), `Setting` is used to extract the first argument of a control object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To initialize and localize `pt`, you should use `DynamicModule` instead of `Manipulate`. Though I think using `Setting` in your code is not the best way to do what it does, however, the un-movable locator issue is NOT simply due to `Setting` but also because both `Manipulate` and `LocatorPane` are trying to dynamically set the value of `pt`, which is the control variable for both of them. So there is a conflict. The solution is simply stripping out `Manipulate` scope.

But there is more thing that should be noticed. `Manipulate` keeps ALL code in its body dynamical. If you strip it out, you'll have to make sure those expressions you expect to be dynamical (*e.g.* `xp = Dynamic[First[pt]]`, `z = Setting[2*xp]` and `` StringForm["x=`1`, z=`2`", xp, z] ``) still be. The simplest way is to wrap them with `Dynamic`.

So a possible solution:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}, xp, z},
 Column[{
   Dynamic[
    xp = First[pt];
    z = 2*xp;
    Style[StringForm["x=`1`, z=`2`", xp, z], Blue, 16]
    ],
   LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],
    ListPlot[{{0, 0}},
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[Dynamic[pt]]},
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, ImageSize -> 600]
    ]
   }, Center]
 ]
```

Just keep in mind that dynamical objects are merely codes which are evaluated on a "thread" called **FrontEnd**, which is parallel to the main kernel thread with some shared variables.

**Edit:**

<strike>It seems the problem is indeed caused by conflicts among `Setting`, `Manipulate` and dynamical controller in `Manipulate` all together.</strike>

*(I completely agree with [Michael E2's explanation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27336/17), so please forget what I said here. Nevertheless, I still suggest people using `DynamicModule` for complicated UI constructions!)*

Interestingly, if we wrap the standalone `y` with `Dynamic`, the "freeze" disappears. This workaround also stands for OP's code. So we can simply write this:

```
Manipulate[
 xp = Dynamic[First[pt]];
 z = Setting[2*xp];
 Column[{
   Style[StringForm["x=`1`, z=`2`", Dynamic[xp], Dynamic[z] ], Blue, 16],
   LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],
    ListPlot[{{0, 0}},
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[Dynamic[pt]]}
     ]]}, Center],
 {{pt, {0, 0}}, None}
 ]
```

However one should be aware this method is not as efficient as the `DynamicModule` solution at the beginning of this answer.

## Conclusion:

In general, I suggest people always avoiding using `Setting` inside `Manipulate`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution is simple, elegant and does work, so I will use it. However, I am still not sure I understand. When in my example I remove Setting, there seems to be no conflict between Manipulate and LocatorPane. The pt coordinates are OK and only 'z' is wrong. What seems to be crucial is having the calculation of xp, z, and the text string within the same Dynamic wrap. I took your code and changed DynamicModule back to Manipulate and it works perfectly as well!

Comment: @MarekPfutzner Thanks. Yes you're right. There is something more here. Though I'm not quite sure what it is right now...

Comment: @MarekPfutzner Please see my edit. I think generally one should avoid using `Setting` inside `Manipulate`.

Comment: Thanks again! I will try to switch into DynamicModule.

Comment: @MarekPfutzner You're welcome.:) I suggest always to construct the interface manually if it's supposed to be complex.

Comment: Very nice. (+1).  Your comment, "There is something more here," led me to offer my own explanation.  I got called away before I could leave a comment for you, but I see you found it already.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks. I went to the wrong way and was so silly to see the true reason..

Answer (score 4):

Your code is very close to correct. I would like to point out some simple changes will put it into a more concise form that still gives everything you wanted.

```
Manipulate[
  Column[{
    Dynamic[xp = First[pt]; z = 2*xp; 
      Style[Row[{xp, "  ", z}], Blue, 16]], 
    LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], ListPlot[{{0, 0}}],
      Appearance -> Graphics@{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}]}]},
    Center],
  {{pt, {0, 0}}, None}]
```

[image: red_locator.png]

Beside the changes involving `Dyanamic` and `Setting` already discussed by Silvia, note the following:

1. `Epilog` has been eliminated. It has been replaced by the `Appearance` option of `LocatorPane`, which is intended to be used to customize the appearance of a locator.
2. `StringForm` has been replaced by `Row`, which is a newer *Mathematica* feature, much more versatile than `StringForm` and something you should be acquainted with.

Comment: +1 for `Appearance`. btw I think `Appearance -> Graphics@{Red,PointSize[Large],Point[{0,0}]}` would be sufficient.

Comment: @Silvia. Thanks for pointing that out. I made an edit incorporating your improvement.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think the problem is with `Setting`.  However, one can avoid using `Setting`, unless for some reason the variable it depends on is unaccessible (a local variable created by a function call, inside a `Module` say).

**Simplest fix to the OP's code**

Put `Dynamic@` in front of `Setting`:

```
Manipulate[
 xp = Dynamic[First[pt]];
 z = Dynamic@Setting[2*xp];
 Column[{Style[StringForm["x=`1`, z=`2`", xp, NumberForm[z, 3]], Blue, 16],
   LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
    ListPlot[{{0, 0}}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[Dynamic[pt]]}]]}, Center],
 {{pt, {0, 0}}, None}]
```

**The way I might do it**

```
f[{x_, y_}] := 2 x;
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Dynamic@Style[StringForm["x=`1`, z=`2`", NumberForm[First[pt], 3],  NumberForm[f[pt], 3]],
          Blue, 16],
   LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
    ListPlot[{{0, 0}}, 
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[Dynamic[pt]]}]]}, Center],
 {{pt, {0, 0}}, None},
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

I used a generic `f` as a placed holder for an arbitrary function; `SaveDefinitions -> True` makes the definition of `f` be saved in the `DynamicModule` created by `Manipulate`.  I also used `NumberForm` to control how many decimals show up.  I might use the `Appearance` option the way @m_goldberg does, too.  Whatever you might think of these alterations, I would avoid using `Setting`.

**Some explanation**

The original code has some constructs that make it a little complicated to understand with respect to dynamic updating.  Nominally the body contains the symbols `xp`, `z`, and of course `pt`, all of which will be tracked.  However `Dynamic[expr]` effectively shields variables in `expr`, which I can perhaps explain most easily by an example from the code.  The expression `xp = Dynamic[pt]` does not depend on `pt`.  If `pt` changes value, the expression inside `Dynamic` will be updated, but expressions outside of `Dynamic` will not be updated (unless for other reasons an update is called for).  In this case the expression inside `Dynamic` is simply `pt`, and I wouldn't be surprised if it is not updated at all, since such expressions are common and have no effect.

Now if we consider the code carefully, we see that all the symbols `pt` appear inside `Dynamic`, except the expression for `z`.  For `z`, we have `Setting[2 * xp]`, which translates into `2 * First[pt]`, without `Dynamic`.  Therefore the body of `Manipulate` depends on `pt` and will be updated when the `Locator` for `pt` is moved.  This causes a new column with a new `LocatorPane` and `Locator` to be created, and it *replaces* the old one.  Thus the dragging of the `Locator` by the mouse is interrupted and stopped.

Now if we remove `Setting`, we see that all the symbols `pt` appear inside `Dynamic`.  The variable `z` now equals `2 * Dynamic[First[pt]]`.  Therefore the body of `Manipulate` does not depend on `pt`, and the body will never be updated.  In particular, the line `z = 2 * xp` is executed only once, when `Manipulate` first starts up.

In the "simplest fix" above, the variable becomes basically equivalent to `Dynamic[2 * First[pt]]`.  While `z` is never updated, the inside of the `Dynamic`, that is, `2 * First[pt]`, is updated whenever the `Locator` moves.

Thus there does not seem to be any special problem with using `Manipulate` here.  The main difference between `Manipulate` and `DynamicModule` is that `Manipulate`, while it creates a `DynamicModule`, does a number of things automatically for you, which can be either convenient or frustrating.  `DynamicModule` allows greater control over things, you have to set everything up yourself, but you get to set it up the way you like.

Comment: +1 You're absolutely right! Why I didn't try `Manipulate[{y, Slider[Dynamic[y]]}, {x, 0, 1}]`!